# how to write dynamic lines from pdf to excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf

`import pdfplumber`

`import openpyxl`

`pdf = pdfplumber.open("path")`

`page = pdf.pages [0]`

`text = page.extract_text()`

`lin = text.split("\n")`

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook ("path")`

`ws= wb.active`

`ws.title = "S1"`

`u = int(0)`

`i = int(1)`

`for u in lin:`

`ws.cell(row = i, column =1).value = lin [u]`

`u = u+1`

`i = i+1`

`wb.save ("path")`

`pdf.close`

`print("Ok!")`

Error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The error occurs on for.

I split each line of the pdf and now I want to write each line in excel.

Example:

line in specific pdf file:

A

B

C

D

I got every line value from the pdf. The variable "lin" for example, has the value A in line 0, the value B in line 1.

I want to take the value of lin 0 and write it in cell A1, and then in the same column take the value of lin 1 and write it in cell A2 in excel and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an integer variable u as the index.

```
u = 0
i = 1
for u in range(len(lin)):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = lin[u]
    u += 1
    i += 1
```

You can also replace the for loop with a for-each loop:

```
for value in lin:
    ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = value
    i += 1
```

In this case you don't need to worry about the index variable.

```
pdf.close()
```